# Why NoClassDefFoundError for com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl in Wildfly?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, cachedrowset

My operating system is Windows 7 64-bit. I am working with Eclipse Luna. I am exploring migration from JBoss 4.2.3 to Wildfly 8.2.1.

I created a simple web app to test out com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl which I believe is part of JDK.

I created a class `RowSetAdaptor` as a wrapper for CachedRowSetImpl class:

```
package com.srh.util;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl;

public class RowSetAdaptor implements Serializable {
   private CachedRowSetImpl rowset;
   public RowSetAdaptor() {
      try {
         rowset = new CachedRowSetImpl();
      } catch (SQLException sqle) {
         System.out.println("RowSetAdaptor: constructor: SQLException=" + sqle);            
      }     
   }
}
```

Then I create a listener class `AppContextListener`:

```
package com.srh.listener;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import com.srh.util.RowSetAdaptor;

public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public AppContextListener() {
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        RowSetAdaptor rsa = null;
        rsa = new RowSetAdaptor();
        System.out.println("AppContextListener: after create: rsa=" + rsa);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    }
}
```

Deploy the app to Jboss 4.2.3 and get the correct output in server.log:

> AppContextListener: after create:
>   rsa=com.srh.util.RowSetAdaptor@2a9073ef

Deploy the same app to Wildfly 8.2.1 and get a NoClassDefFoundError in server.log for CachedRowSetImpl :

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl

Since com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl is part of JDK so why is Wildfly giving this error? I am confused. How to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed these steps to resolve this issue:

Open `module.xml` of JDK located in `modules/system/layers/base/sun/jdk/main` directory.

Include these 3 lines under paths element:

```
<path name="com/sun/rowset"/>
<path name="com/sun/rowset/internal"/>
<path name="com/sun/rowset/providers"/>
```

Save `module.xml`

Restart Wildfly

Don't know why Wildfly JDK module does not come with these 3 lines already.